# How can I clear freebsd caсhe

Tags: freebsd, cache

I used scp to copy a file from another system. After copy has finished I want to clear the cache.
My os is FreeBS 9.2.

Can I do this and how should I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Sven I want to get MD5 of source file and destination file and compare them.

Comment: Please go through older post [dropping-cached-memory-on-freebsd](https://serverfault.com/questions/373184/dropping-cached-memory-on-freebsd)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `sync(1)`